# Singular versus plural in certain locutions: Is there a name for this?

Tags: terminology, morphology, linguistic-typology, grammatical-number, compounds

- I wouldn't touch that idea with a ten-foot pole.
- He's a tool maker.
- In Germany, Catholics and Lutherans pay a church tax.
- The zebra stripes indicate a pedestrian crossing.
- He is a resident of an Indian reservation.
- He is from the Klingon homeworld.

In English one does not refer to a "ten-feet pole" or a "tools maker" or a "churches tax" or a "pedestrians crossing" or an "Indians reservation" or the "Klingons homeworld", despite the clear-cut non-singularity in each instance.  But in corresponding locutions in German, the plural form is always used.

- Is there a name for this distinction or for either of the two modes of expression?
- Is there an account of this in popular, or at least relatively non-technical, published expository sources?
- Is this an instance of something more general that linguists have a concept for?
- What can be said about this that is of interest besides the brute observation that the phenomenon exists?

Comment: Great question. Couple of comments: First, the generalisation that plural forms aren't allowed compound-internally in Eng. isn't so clear-cut. Consider: (a) *rat-infested*, (a') *rats-infested*, (b) *mouse-infested*, (b') *mice-infested*. Most speakers find (b') to be an awful lot better than (a') (consider also *lice brush*, *teeth marks*, etc.). The generalisation appears to be that **regular** plurals are dispreferred. Second thing: Can you provide some examples from German? I think you're probably right, but i want to be clear we aren't confusing fugen-s for a plural marker.

Comment: @PElliott "Kirchensteuer" (church tax), "Kinderlied" (song for children).  I haven't mentally cataloged a list of examples in German.  I'll post more as I come across them.  "Ten-foot pole" certainly involves a "strong" noun, so if that counts as an irregular plural, then maybe that's an exception to the rule you're proposing.

Comment: A Yankees fan, an antiques shop, the situation is not so clear-cut in English either.

Comment: There's a post on Arnold Zwicky's blog where he discusses numerous counter-examples to the putative generalisation for English. Might be of interest to you: http://arnoldzwicky.org/2010/12/05/data-points-plurals-in-compounds-12510/

Comment: I guess we've discussed whether "pedestrian" is a noun or an adjective in other comments. I also see "Indian" and "Klingon" as adjectives, as I would say "English reservation" and "English homeworld", not "England reservation" or "England homeworld".

Answer (score 2):

All of your examples involve compounds (even though the two parts of the compound are in most cases written as separate words). English has inherited from Indo-European the principle that the first part of a compound (Vorderglied) is as a rule not inflected for number or case.

Some of your (implied) German examples are of the same sort: Zebra(streifen), Indianer(reservation) have an uninflected Vorderglied. Others have a Vorderglied in the genitive singular: Kirchen(steuer) follows the old weak declension of Kirche (Kirchen in all cases except nom. sing.), a type also well attested in ancient IE languages.

Comment: Can you give examples from *non*-Indo-European languages in which the Vorderglied is a regular plural form? I'm not prima facie convinced that this is just a contingent fact about IE.

Comment: I am not sure that any other language families have IE-type compounds.

Comment: Actually, I didn't even have in mind "zebra stripes" as one of my examples.  "Pedestrian crossing" is what I had in mind.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, in "pedestrian crossing", I interpret "pedestrian" as an adjective.

Comment: "English has inherited from Indo-European the principle that the first part of a compound (Vorderglied) is as a rule not inflected for number or case", but "Others have a Vorderglied in the genitive singular: [...] a type also well attested in ancient IE languages." Do these contradict each other?

Comment: We normally assume that the type with uninflected VG is older, and the type with VG in a case form is more recent. Both types are common in (for example) Sanskrit and Greek, but the uninflected type is much more common.

Comment: @dainichi : I don't think it makes sense to interpret "pedestrian" as an adjective in that case.  It is not the crossing that is pedestrian, but the people, that are pedestrians.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, do you pronounce "pedestrian crossing" without stress (or with only secondary stress) on "crossing", like "station" in "police station"? I have primary stress on "crossing". AFAIK, noun-noun compounds only have primary stress on the first element.

Comment: In principle I agree with what you say about stress. However, if the compound is very long it can have two main stresses in English; e.g. “university professor” is definitely a compound, but it has two main stresses.

Comment: @dainichi The primary stress in the whole two-word phrase as I pronounce it is on the second syllable of "pedestrian".

Comment: @fdb, yeah, you're right, the argument doesn't really work for long compounds.